# Iframe content not loading in Iphone after IOS15 upgrade

Tags: iphone, iframe, ios15

We have a custom application embedded in an iframe and the content inside the iframe is not loading only in Iphone after the ios is upgraded to ios15. The same application is working fine in IOS14. This issue is seen both safari and chrome browsers after IOS15 upgrade.
The same application works fine in Android Mobiles and Desktop mobiles.   Are there any known issues with IOS15 with respect to Iframe? Any pointers to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

-- Satish.

Answer (score 0):

My English is poor,I'll try to be as concise as possible.
Because IOS15 cannot use iframe to embed cross-domain web sites.
Some solutions:

- Redeploy the custom application embedded in the iframe,ensure that the site in the iframe is in the same domain as the parent page.Avoid cross domain.
- or,Configure proxy forwarding to the server where the parent site is deployed,For example, nginx configures proxy forwarding to the application embedded in an iframe.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation/release notes which says that this is a limitation in IOS15. Both the above solutions will not work for us and need to convince customer that this is a limitation from IOS15 to change the entire design of the page now.